# Calling an async function from main in C#

Tags: c#, async-await

I am trying to wrap my head around `async await` in C#. I have written this small windows console app that has two files.

`Downloader.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AsyncAwait
{
    public class Downloader
    {

        public async Task DownloadFilesAsync()
        {
            // In the Real World, we would actually do something...
            // For this example, we're just going to print file 0, file 1.
            await DownloadFile0();
            await DownloadFile1();
        }
        public async Task DownloadFile0()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Downloading File 0");
            await Task.Delay(100);
        }

        public async Task DownloadFile1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Downloading File 1");
            await Task.Delay(100);
        }
    }
}
```

`Program.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AsyncAwait
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Downloader d = new Downloader();

        }
    }
}
```

I just want to call the function `DownloadFilesAsync()` from my `main`. I have created the `Downloader` object 'd'. However since it is main and return type has to be void it is not possible. What is a way around this?

Comment: https://www.bing.com/search?q=calling+an+async+function+from+main+in+c%23

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 Task.Run(async () => { await d.DownloadFilesAsync();}).Wait();
```